# Making edits to .then() in a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I have this sequelize controller below:

```
const Category = require('../models').category;

module.exports = {
  list(req, res) {
    return Category
      .all({attributes: ['title']})
      .then(categories => res.status(200).send(categories))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  }
};
```

Essentially, returning `Category.all({attributes: ['title']})` results in this array:

```
[
  {"title": "video"},
  {"title": "gif"},
  {"title": "website"}
]
```

I want to add the object `{"title": "all"}` to the beginning of the array, by doing something like this:

```
const Category = require('../models').category;

module.exports = {
  list(req, res) {
    return Category
      .all({attributes: ['title']})
      .then(categories => 
        categories.unshift({"title": "all"})
        res.status(200).send(categories)
      )
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  }
};
```

But I know this is not exactly correct. How, when handling promises and the `.then()` statement, can I edit the categories array in the `.then()` statement? Thanks!

Comment: note: you could do `.then(categories => res.status(200).send([{"title": "all"}, ...categories]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.then(categories => {
        categories.unshift({"title": "all"})
        res.status(200).send(categories)
      })
```

Just need to add curly braces around the code in the then statement so it’s not an implied return.